# How to update a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm  new in Python and recently I am stuck in a nested dictionary. 
I have a nested dictionary where 018-11-07 11:04:42.747458957 (time) is the outer key 1, and 0.74,0.74..... is the inner key (price) and 3000,2000 is the value (size).

```
    d = defaultdict(dict)   
    for index, row in dfall.iterrows():                                                             
        d[index][row['Bid_Price']] = row['Bid_Size']                      

    for k, v in d.items():                                         
        print(k,v)                                                       

    #output                                                                  
    018-11-07 11:04:42.747458957 {0.74: 3000.0}   
    018-11-07 11:04:42.747585906 {0.74: 2000.0}                                                    
    018-11-07 11:06:45.370588295 {0.725: 50000.0}                        
    018-11-07 11:41:55.490215944 {0.73: 99900.0}                      
    018-11-07 14:32:05.699281479 {0.73: 109900.0}
```

I'm looking to use loop to update the existing outer key with new value and add new outer key if it doesn't have it in the dictionary. So, it is like updating the existing key and value add in new key and value while reading down the rows.

So, the expected outcome would be like

```
    018-11-07 11:04:42.747458957 {0.74: 3000.0}                          
    018-11-07 11:04:42.747585906 {0.74: 2000.0}                          
    018-11-07 11:06:45.370588295 {0.74: 2000.0},{0.725:50000.0}                            
    018-11-07 11:41:55.490215944 {0.74: 2000.0},{0.725:50000.0},{0.73:99900.0}                                                               
    018-11-07 14:32:05.699281479 {0.74: 2000.0},{0.725:50000.0},{0.73:109900.0}
```

Thank you very much for any reply.

Comment: You need change the inner dictionary to a list of dictionaries.

Comment: What about if you had a dict of lists? The lists hold dicts themselves. It is basically what you wrote down in your expected outcomes. You can easily build that with a `defaultdict()`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry for partially understanding your reply as I'm really new to programming. Hence it would be better if you could shed light by providing me some codes which I can digest? Thanks